# CAML search ignoring diacritics

Tags: 2010, caml-query

A rather strange request has appeared from our client, who wants to be able to search a SharePoint 2010 list for items (based on a string column) while ignoring diacritics.

A quick example, assuming this is a list with IDs and two columns:

`1. Paweł | Marciniak`

`2. Pawel | Jankowski`

then searching the first column for `PAWEL` (or `PAWEŁ` for that matter) should return both items.

Can it be done using CAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible using CAML alone.

But you may create an extra hidden column FirstNameNormalized, and update that with an EventReceiver on ItemAdded/ItemUpdated using a nomalized string like the one from [Stripping is an interesting job](http://www.siao2.com/2007/05/14/2629747.aspx).

Then when you're filtering you can do that on FirstNameNormalized using a likewise normalized string.

Comment: That was my initial idea, but I was hoping there was some way of making CAML do the work for me. Thanks for the answer.